# What is the Marketshare of the big three video editing (NLE) software packages?

Tags: premiere, video-editor, final-cut-pro, avid

Cannot find a source to see market share or change for top video editing software tools used today.

The big three are:
Avid
Final Cut Pro
Adobe Premiere Pro (after effects)

I know Avid is still used by large film and movie productions.
But from the grass roots perspective, every day users, it seems to be overwhelmingly Adobe products. But this is based on my anecdotal personal perspective. Wanted something more concrete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of data is actually remarkably hard to come by.  There are a few industry reports available for thousands of dollars, but the best free resource I could find when I was searching was an informal poll that Dave Dugdale did.  It was an imperfect test by his own admission because it allowed both voting up and voting down, but it gives at least some kind of an idea of the rough market share.

Comment: Yes, I also found interesting survey by PBS, were they sampled a small number of filmmakers, producers, editors (those that work in the documentary field). Interesting to see the gear used and NLE used. http://www.pbs.org/pov/filmmakers/2013-documentary-equipment-survey.php

Comment: I really liked the google trends tool, but the interesting thing if you localize the region to the United States, FCP and Premiere are practically neck and neck in search interest (I used the software term instead of local search to get a better range of interest). I never realized that FCP was that big. Avid was almost non existant but sony vegas pro came a decent 3rd. Worldwide Sony Vegas was number 1.

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting survey.

On a youtube talk forum, a straw count was taken asking users what their favorite editing software was (NLE). Out of a sample size of 104 this is how it broke down below (I added my preferences as well, premiere pro and screenflow)

23% [Sony Vegas Pro](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/vegaspro) 
23% [Premiere Pro](http://www.adobe.com/ca/products/premiere.html) 
13% [Windows Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-live/movie-maker) 
8% [Final Cut Pro X](https://www.apple.com/ca/final-cut-pro/) 
6% [iMovie](https://www.apple.com/ca/mac/imovie/) 
4% [Camtasia Studio](https://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) 
4% [Corel Video Studio](http://www.videostudiopro.com/en/products/videostudio/pro/) 
3% [VideoPad](http://www.nchsoftware.com/videopad/) 
2% [Lightworks](https://www.lwks.com/) 
2% [Magic Movie Edit Pro](http://www.magix.com/ca/movie-edit-pro/) 
2% [HitFilm](https://hitfilm.com/) 
2% [Power Director Pro](http://www.cyberlink.com/products/powerdirector-ultra/features_en_CA.html) 
2% [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm) 
1% [Sony Movie Studio](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/moviestudiope) 
1% [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/) (Linux) 
1% [Filmora](http://filmora.wondershare.com/) 
1% [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) 
1% [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) 
1% [AVS Editor](http://www.avs4you.com/AVS-Video-Editor.aspx) 
1% [VideoStudio](http://www.videostudiopro.com/en/products/videostudio/ultimate/)

Notable mentions:

1, [Avid](https://www.avid.com/US/Solutions/byNeed/video-editing.html), 1 person mentioned it, but they were forced to use it in a university program, otherwise at home, for actual video editing work they used another tool. So I left it out since it was not exactly a glowing endorsement.

2, [Davinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/ca/products/davinciresolve/edit), another surprise. A wonderful free program that came out when black magic 4K video camera came out. But no-one in the youtube community is using it yet. Actually I use premiere pro myself, but still thought more people would be using this one.

(Source: http://yttalk.com/threads/what-does-everyone-use-for-editing.171578/)